# I broke encrypted swap partition. How do I bring it back?

Tags: encryption, swap, cryptsetup

I installed Kubuntu 15.04 a while ago with encrypted home and swap partitions. Everything worked as a charm, but today I decided to install Kali Linux on another partition as well (no encryption anywhere, need it to work).

I forgot about encrypted swap partition and thought that it might be a good idea to share swap, so I formatted it as a regular swap. Now I have no idea how to revert to previous configuration. I'm trying to format it again as a regular swap partition, `swapon` it and then use `ecryptfs-setup-swap` but it freezes after this:

```
Do you want to proceed with encrypting your swap? [y/N]: y

INFO: Setting up swap: [/dev/sda5]
cryptdisks stop/waiting
```

I don't really need swap to my Kali Linux, but please help me with bringing back Kubuntu encrypted swap.

Answer (score 1):

I had to start from scratch, everything works great now.

This article was a life-saver: http://iwtf.net/2010/01/05/encrypting-your-ubuntu-swap-partition/

In case the link gets moved, basically all I had to do is:

1. format as swap
2. Add this line to `/etc/crypttab`:

   ```
   sudo echo cryptoswap /dev/sda5 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256,hash=sha256,swap
   ```
3. and add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/cryptoswap none swap sw 0 0
   ```

After reboot everything works. I can share encrypted swap space between both distros.