# Trouble with getting my swap partition encrypted

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap

I followed the answer in this question: [i broke encrypted swap partition. how to bring it back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566382/i-broke-encrypted-swap-partition-how-to-bring-it-back#new-answer?newreg=9ab54f537bd049638764e91e29abd3cdI)

And now I am being prompted for a passphrase on booting.  Did, I miss something?  Should I have a key file?  Thank you!

My crypttab file reads:

```
cryptoswap /dev/sdc3 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256,hash=sha256,swap
```

Comment: Your key file is `/dev/urandom` (which produces pseudo-random data), which is correct for swap. Did anything change recently before it started to ask for a password? Can you bypass it and still boot, or are you locked out right now? And what does the password prompt exactly say for which device it needs a password?

Comment: I was able to boot by just pressing enter on the dialog.  I removed the encryption from the fstab file, until I got a solution.  The ls -l output for the key file was: "crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 9 Jan  7 12:14 /dev/urandom".  So it exists.  Thanks for the help.